# Override/change name of fields in JSON response in API Platform

Tags: api, symfony, pagination

I am working on an API Platform 3 (Symfony 6) app.

In my JSON response, I have the following :

{
...
"totalItems": 7065,
"itemsPerPage": 10,
...
}

Is it possible to change the config so that I get :

{
...
"total_items": 7065,
"page_size": 10,
...
}

So basically I want to rename these fields, in the response I get. Is it possible ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The custom normalizer is the solution to this question.

A custom event listener is also a solution but it is not GraphQL friendly.

Answer (score 0):

If your question is about parameter names for pagination only, so then you can just execute `bin/console debug:config api_platform` and you will see available config parameters ([documentation](https://api-platform.com/docs/core/pagination/#pagination)) under `api_platform.collection.pagination`:

```
collection:
    pagination:
        page_parameter_name: page
        items_per_page_parameter_name: perPage
        enabled: true
        partial: false
        client_enabled: false
        client_items_per_page: false
        client_partial: false
        items_per_page: 30
        maximum_items_per_page: null
        enabled_parameter_name: pagination
        partial_parameter_name: partial
```

Hope you will find what you want. Anyway, you can always to find the place where this piece is serialized and try to decorate/override it.

Otherwise, if you want to change the name of some another parameter from api resource you can use `SerializedName()` attribute on this property

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your answer. It is not possible to override the names of these fields through config. Through SerializedName() either, because these properties (totalItems and itemsPerPage) are not defined in any entity, they come from API Platform itself. So maybe define a custom normalizer and try to override these names in the normalizer.

Comment: So the custom normalizer is the solution to this question.

Comment: So, I've wrote about it too in my answer)